# Android - Cannot share vCard from internal cache

Tags: android, caching, file-sharing

I am using a ShareActionProvider to share a vcf file I created.

If I store the file in the external cache, I have absolutely no problems sharing the file, but if I store it in the internal cache, every app I try to share the vCard with says the file is corrupted or unsupported.

I read the file after creating it, and in both cases they are exactly the same.

This code works:

```
File dir = new File(getExternalCacheDir() + "/contact");
dir.mkdirs();
vcfFile = new File(dir, name.replace(' ', '+') + ".vcf");
```

However, if I use `getCacheDir()` instead, I get the problem.

Here's the code for creating the file:

```
FileWriter fw;
    try {
        fw = new FileWriter(vcfFile);
        fw.write("BEGIN:VCARD\r\n");
        fw.write("VERSION:2.1\r\n");
        fw.write("N:" + codedName + "\r\n");
        fw.write("FN:" + name + "\r\n");
        fw.write("ORG:" + org + "\r\n");
        fw.write("TITLE:" + position + "\r\n");
        fw.write("TEL;PREF;WORK;VOICE;ENCODING=QUOTED-PRINTABLE:" + phone + "\r\n");
        fw.write("TEL;PREF;WORK;FAX;ENCODING=QUOTED-PRINTABLE:" + fax + "\r\n");
        fw.write("ADR;WORK;;ENCODING=QUOTED-PRINTABLE:" + codedAddr + "\r\n");
        fw.write("EMAIL;INTERNET:" + email + "\r\n");
        fw.write("URL;WORK:" + website + "\r\n");
        fw.write("PHOTO;TYPE=JPEG;ENCODING=BASE64:" + codedImage + "\r\n");
        fw.write("END:VCARD\r\n");
        fw.close();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
```

And here's the code for the ShareActionProvider:

```
provider = (ShareActionProvider) menu.findItem(R.id.share).getActionProvider();

    if (provider != null) {
        Intent intent = new Intent();
        intent.setAction(Intent.ACTION_SEND);
        intent.setType("text/vcard");
        intent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_STREAM, Uri.fromFile(vcfFile));
        provider.setShareIntent(intent);
    }
```

Any ideas of what I'm doing wrong?

Answer (score 0):

> Any ideas of what I'm doing wrong?
>
> *every app I try to share the vCard with says the file is corrupted or unsupported.*

According with [Using the Internal Storage](http://developer.android.com/intl/es/guide/topics/data/data-storage.html#filesInternal)

> You can save files directly on the device's internal storage. By default, files saved to the internal storage are **private to your application** and **other applications cannot access them** (nor can the user)...

For this reason, it is advisable to use **External Storage**

#### Manifest

uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"

#### Code

```

```
public void sharePublicContact(View view){

    String name = "Mickey Mouse";
    String org = "Disney Corp.";
    String note = "";

    File dir = new File(getExternalCacheDir() + "/contact");
    dir.mkdirs();
    File vcfFile = new File(dir, name.replace(' ', '+') + ".vcf");

    FileWriter fw;
    try {

        fw = new FileWriter(vcfFile);
        fw.write("BEGIN:VCARD\r\n");
        fw.write("VERSION:3.0\r\n");
        fw.write("FN:" + name + "\r\n");
        fw.write("ORG:" + org + "\r\n");
        fw.write("NOTE:" + note + "\r\n");
        fw.write("END:VCARD\r\n");
        fw.close();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    Intent sendIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_SEND);
    sendIntent.setType("text/vcard");
    sendIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_STREAM, Uri.fromFile(vcfFile));

    startActivity(sendIntent);
}
```

```